# Using arrays and methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have a question on how to use arrays and methods. In my case, I am trying to write a method that calculates and displays the average when given a specific letter, but the letters are in an array. When I call my method, it says `incompatible types: String[] cannot be converted to String`. How can I fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class Tester{
public double letterAverage(String letterGrade){
    double letterAverage = 0;
    if(letterGrade == "a"){
        System.out.println(99 / 4);
    }else if(letterGrade == "b"){
        System.out.println(88 / 2);
    }else{
        System.out.println(77 / 3);
    }
    return letterAverage;
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c"};
    letterAverage(letters); // error
}
}
```

Comment: 1. Do not use arrays, use collections (ArrayList in this case)
2. public double letterAverage(String[] letterGrade) if you want to pass an array, but then the body is wrong
3. Write an algorithm first, then implement it in a language of your choice -- you are lacking the algorithm here
4. And yes, thanks @rgettman, use `equals()`

Comment: First, use `String`'s `equals` method to compare string values, not the `==` operator.  Second, you are passing an array of strings where a single string is expected.  Pass one string instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your letterAverage method is expecting a String but you are passing an array of strings (String[]).

You need to change your method so that it accepts an array of strings, and probably change the implementation to account for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Man, try this

```
String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c"};
for (String s : letters)
     letterAverage(s);
```

And change this

```
if(letterGrade == "a")
```

to this

```
if("a".equals(letter))
```

This is a valid way to compare String, using `equals()`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I changed the sentence, saying that it is valid way, so there is other ways like you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String[] letters = {"a", "b", "c"};
    for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
        letterAverage(letters[i]); // error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are excellent answers already on how to use your method as is. However, if you input is a list of grades, maybe you want a list of averages back in the same order. For that you can do the following:

```
public class Tester {
    public static double[] letterAverage(String... letterGrades) {
        double[] averages = new double[letterGrades.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < letterGrades.length; i++) {
            String letterGrade = letterGrades[i];
            double letterAverage = 0;
            if (letterGrade == "a") {
                System.out.println(99 / 4);
            } else if (letterGrade == "b") {
                System.out.println(88 / 2);
            } else {
                System.out.println(77 / 3);
            }
            averages[i] = letterAverage;
        }
        return averages;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String[] letters = { "a", "b", "c" };
        double[] averages = letterAverage(letters);
    }
}
```